# Button not fully clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I just programmed an own windows without Windows Border. So my Exit Button is just a Button in the upper right corner. This Button is not fully clickable, that means i can just click the upper 5 pixles of the Button. After that, the button is not reacting for hover or even clicking.
Although i tried to put the button somwhere else, it is working in the middle of the window, but it is not working on the upper side of the window.

It just looks right.
[image: The Button in the upper right corner]

In Snoop nothing is overlaying the button.
[image]

Here is my Code, I can't find the Reason.

```
<Window x:Class="LatikeManager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LatikeManager"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Project LATIKE"  
    Icon="Resources/pcc.ico" 
    Height="800" 
    Width="1000" 
    Background="#FF222525" 
    MinHeight="400" 
    MinWidth="500" 
    WindowStyle="None" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    SizeToContent="Manual"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Border BorderThickness="1">
    <!--complete grid-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--title & window settings-->
        <Grid Background="#FF131212">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--Title-->
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="25" Height="25" Margin="2 2 2 2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 0 0" Foreground="LightGray" FontWeight="Bold">Project LATIKE - Latike Manager</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <!--Window settings-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button>x</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
        <!--menuebar to load different modes-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Name="spMenu" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF131212">
                <!--Roommanager-->
                <ToggleButton Name="tbtRoomManager">
                    <ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <!--<Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="25" Height="25" Stretch="Uniform"/>-->
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="5 2 0 0"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
                </ToggleButton>
                <!--Roomdesigner-->
                <!--<ToggleButton Name="tbtRoomDesigner">
                <ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="25" Height="25" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="5 2 0 0">Raumdesigner</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
            </ToggleButton>-->
                <!--Settings-->
                <ToggleButton Name="tbtSettings">
                    <ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <!--<Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="25" Height="25" Stretch="Uniform"/>-->
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="5 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
                </ToggleButton>
            </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
        <!--content loader: load and shows the modes-->
        <Grid Name="gdManagerContent" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <!--State- and eventbar-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Background="#FF131212" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--actual eventbar-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="10 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White">Ereignisse:</TextBlock>
                <Image Width="25" Height="25" Margin="2 0 2 0" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" MinWidth="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin=" 15 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Width="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Gray" />
            <!--linkbar-->
            <StackPanel Margin="5 0 0 0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Fortschritt :" Width="70" Foreground="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Width="70" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Width="25" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="s" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <Grid Margin="7 0 3 0">
                        <ProgressBar  Width="100" Height="10"></ProgressBar>
                        <StackPanel Width="100" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="20 0 0 0" Width="25" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Width="30" Text="MB/s" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
                <Grid Width="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Gray" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0" TextAlignment="Right" Width="120" Foreground="Gray" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                <Image Width="25" Height="25" Stretch="Uniform" Margin=" 10 2 5 5"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <!--Console-->
        <!--<Grid Grid.Row="4">
                <RichTextBox Name="rtbConsole" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="100" Background="#FF131212" Foreground="White" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="{Binding ConsoleText}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox>
        </Grid>-->
    </Grid>
</Border>
</Window>
```

It is the same behavior without the Theme.

Comment: You could try to [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) it in order to find the piece that's overlapping your button.

Comment: I just used Snoop, i could not find anything overlaying the Button.

Comment: can you share the style of Button of you used? Default button will show like this

Comment: i just added the button theme code

Comment: @DonKnash with your button style. im getting exception on MouseOver, remove the mouseover animation. and check

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your issue is not reproducible based on the markup you have posted. You should remove all event handlers and add all resources that you are referencing.

Comment: @mm8 i just removed all handlers and resources. Thank you

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your issue. It's unclear how the ButtonStyle is being applied to the Button. It isn't in your sample markup.

Comment: even without the Theme, the button shows still the same behavior

Comment: @DonKnash Create a separate project and remove all unnecessary code until you have a [MCVE]

Comment: @TheLethalCoder i just tried it in a new project and it worked, so how can i just find out why it is not working in my porject ?

Comment: @DonKnash Copy the project and slowly remove the code until a) It works and you now know what is causing the problem or b) It still doesn't and you have an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the error. I just used this to get the Windows 7 upwards features to my window without the Windows style.

```
WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, new WindowChrome());
```

But because i just did not display the border, it was transparent blocking the buttons.
Removing this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming this is your button`s code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
    <Button>x</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Where exactly do you handle the click on the button? You should give it a click event or some command handling.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
    <Button Command="CloseTheApplicationCommand">x</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

If above doesn`t work, check which events in the snoop do occur. Perhaps you should handle the button using the "pre..." events.

Comment: They are "Preview" events and they are not a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: Sorry i just removed all the events due to a comment. In my app there are Events, and i can fire these event, but just on 5 pixels of the button.